# How to concatWith using information from previous Observable for pagination

Tags: pagination, rx-java2

Let's say I have a blocking method with is called `List<UUID> listOf(int page)`.
If I want to paginate something like this, one idea is to do something like this:

```
public Observable<UUID> allOf(int initialPage) {
    return fromCallable( () -> listOf(initialPage))
            .concatWith( fromCallable( () -> allOf(initialPage + 1)))
            .flatMap(x -> from(x));
}
```

If my service doesn't use the page number but the last element of the list to find next elements, how can I achieve it with `RxJava`?

I would still like to obtain the effect of doing something like `allOf(0).take(20)` and obtain, with `concatWith`, the call to the second Observable when the first one has completed.

But how can I do it when I need information from the previous call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subject to send back the next page number to the beginning of a sequence:

```
List<Integer> service(int index) {
    System.out.println("Reading " + index);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = index; i < index + 20; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    return list;
}

Flowable<List<Integer>> getPage(int index) {
    FlowableProcessor<Integer> pager = UnicastProcessor.<Integer>create()
        .toSerialized();
    pager.onNext(index);

    return pager.observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline(), true, 1)
    .map(v -> {
        List<Integer> list = service(v);
        pager.onNext(list.get(list.size() - 1) + 1);
        return list;
    })
    ;
}

@Test
public void testPager() {
    getPage(0).take(20)
    .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
}
```

Comment: Why trampoline?

Comment: To avoid recursive onNext calls.